# Подскажите слайдер с миниатюрами на html+javascript+css (не jQuery!)

Tags: javascript, slider

Подскажите легкий бесплатный слайдер с миниатюрами на html+javascript+css (не jQuery!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый пример : [Первый](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow)
Вот второй пример : [Второй](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_gallery)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/703757)

Comment: @Dmitry всё возможно в этой жизнь)